# How to remove default option from dropdown list in <h:selectOneMenu>

Tags: html, jsf, drop-down-menu, selectonemenu

I am working on a JSF page which has a dropdown based on selectOneMenu

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="speciality_unit" value="#{editCdc.selectedUnit}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Select Unit" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{editCdc.listOfUnit}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The problem I am facing here is that whenever I select this dropdown, it shows the default option in the list along with other items. I.e. it shows "Select Unit" along with other units. I want to remove this "Select Unit" from the dropdown list. How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide it using CSS.

```
<h:selectOneMenu ... styleClass="hideFirstOption">
```

```
select.hideFirstOption option:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```